# How do I $templateCache.get the content for app.config from a templates.js file?

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, gruntjs

I think it's quite well put in the title already, but what I'm trying to do, is have a template content from $templateCache.get(); I've tried to Dependency Inject $templateCache to different parts of the app.config

```
...
...
.config(['$routeProvider', '$templateCache', function($routeProvider, $templateCache) {

$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        template : function ($templateCache) {return $templateCache.get('main.html');}
    }).
```

This results in $templateCache is not a function.

My app.js is its own module and templates.js is linked in the index file after the app.js file. Template.js file is created by a Grunt task and it puts the content stuff  their repected templates.

I saw some question here that had templateCache iterated and the content from there put into templateCache in the app.run part so I quess my question is whether I can somehow use my template.js that uses app.run to put() into the $templateCache, or do I have to refactor my Grunt task to build it into a json object? Any plnkr and/or resources would help. Sorry for being vague.

Answer (score 2):

Why aren't you using directly the templateCache Id of your tempalte (it's filepath/filename if it's html2js-ified) ? Angular will automatically load it from templateCache if a matching templateCache Key exists :

```
$routeProvider.
    when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'main.html'
    })
```

Comment: It doesn't exist yet. I have templates on a separate angular module - templates.js, but it gets called after app.js file/module. I have tried both what you suggested and what I have in my Q but they, expectedly so, give an error because either the templateCache is not allocated or the templateCache key doesn't exist. Writing this, I realise that changing from ngRoute to ngUiRouter won't fix it. Should I just grunt the compiled templates to a JSON file and populate templateCache from that?